# Error with debug build of MFC application with AFX_IDB_CHECKLISTBOX_95

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have suddenly started to encounter a error when running my application. I place a breakpoint on the offending line:

```
m_lbWeeks.SetCheck(iIndex, BST_CHECKED);
```

[image]

[image]

The listbox is of type `CMyCheckListBox` which is derived from `CCheckListBox`:

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>
class CMyCheckListBox :
    public CCheckListBox
{

public:
    
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
    {
        // set item height once:    
        if ((GetStyle() & (LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS)) ==
            (LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS) && m_cyText == 0)
        {
            SetItemHeight(0, CalcMinimumItemHeight() + 2);
        }

        // add some space between box and string: 
        lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.left += 2;

        CCheckListBox::DrawItem(lpDrawItemStruct);
    }
};
```

And `iIndex` has a value of `0`. It is failing here:

```
_AFX_CHECKLIST_STATE::_AFX_CHECKLIST_STATE()
{
    m_sizeCheck = CSize(0, 0);

    CBitmap bitmap;

    VERIFY(bitmap.LoadBitmap(AFX_IDB_CHECKLISTBOX_95));
    m_hbitmapCheck = (HBITMAP)bitmap.Detach();

    // Cannot initialize here since conctl32.dll may not yet be loaded and/or
    // this code is executed during DllMain 
    m_dwVerComCtl32 = 0;
}
```

The `VERIFY` line. I never used to have this problem although recently I updated Visual Studio to the latest update.

This error:

1. Only happens in DEBUG mode. Although if I click Ignore it appears to continue to run (as in - I see check boxes).
2. Only happens when running the application in non-English with satellite DLL.

I saw this [article](https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/dPj2mQWP/loadbitmap-failure-for-afx-idb-checklistbox-95) but their issue was in reverse.

The resource ID itself is known (`30996`) and located in `afxres.h`. But the resource itself appears to not load. Even though if we hit ignore it when still shows a check box. The combo is set as "Has Strings" and Owner Draw "Fixed".

---

I am now really confused.

If I run a third party application called appTranslator, and create new project and select the debug build of my EXE, I can see the 30996 bitmap in the resources. But when I select the release build of the exe, this bitmap is not displayed!  All crazy ...

---

Delving into the core RC files in Visual Studio I see this in afxres.rc:

```
#ifndef _AFX_INTL_RESOURCES

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMiniFrameWnd Bitmap

AFX_IDB_MINIFRAME_MENU      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE     "res\\minifwnd.bmp"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CCheckListBox Bitmaps

AFX_IDB_CHECKLISTBOX_95     BITMAP  DISCARDABLE     "res\\95check.bmp"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#endif // _AFX_INTL_RESOURCES
```

So the resource is only included if `_AFX_INTL_RESOURCES` is not defined. I can't go any further now. Headache.

---

## Update

I decided to add my own code into my main dialog `OnInitDialog` to see what was happening:

```
    CBitmap bmp;
    
    if (!bmp.LoadBitmap(AFX_IDB_CHECKLISTBOX_95))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("1. Bitmap was not loaded"));
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("1. Bitmap was loaded"));
        bmp.Detach();
    }
    

    LPCTSTR lpszResourceName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(AFX_IDB_CHECKLISTBOX_95);
    HINSTANCE hinstRes = AfxFindResourceHandle(lpszResourceName, RT_BITMAP);
    if (hinstRes != nullptr)
    {
        HBITMAP hbmp = (HBITMAP) ::LoadImage(hinstRes, lpszResourceName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
        if (hbmp != nullptr)
        {
            bmp.Attach(hbmp);
            AfxMessageBox(_T("2. Bitmap was loaded"));
        }
        else
            AfxMessageBox(_T("2. Bitmap was not loaded"));

    }
```

If I compile and run my application in Release build for any language (using satellite DLL files) both instances returns that the bitmap was loaded. So it is actually being found which is good news.

If I compile and run my software in Debug 64 bit in English, it too finds the resources and loads the bitmap. It is only when I try to run the software in Debug for non-English that causes the issue. I have been using the "Release" satellite DLL files which doesn't seem acceptable. And appTranslator doesn't seem to work correctly if I try to build DLL files for a Debug executable. Since appTranslator is no longer maintained I think I must just acknowledge that this is technically not a problem for me because I don't release Debug builds anyway.

Comment: *"Only happens in DEBUG mode."* - Of course, that's how the [VERIFY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/diagnostic-services#verify) macro works: *"In the Release version of MFC, VERIFY evaluates the expression but does not print or interrupt the program."* The Release configuration presumably fails just as well, yet doesn't report the failure. The core issue is probably related to the (non-standard) way you implemented your multi-language support.

Comment: @IInspectable I have a checkbox. It is functional. And appTranslator creates mfc satellite dll files which I load correctly.

Comment: The image resource isn't used for standard checkbox controls. It is used with list-view controls (prior to version 6 of the common controls). The `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` [extended list-view styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/extended-list-view-styles) documentation provides a tiny glimpse into the internals of the list-view implementation in version 4.70.

Comment: @IInspectable What I mean is, my "CCheckListBox" control works - irrespective of this error as it I have tick able checkboxes. This is not a list view control (not that I am aware of).

Comment: @IInspectable Side note: I know of no other way to easily manage all of my language dll translations and create the dll files without paying for expensive software.

Comment: `CCheckListBox` has 2 distinct implementations to render the checkbox visuals, depending on whether [IsAppThemed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-isappthemed) returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If Visual Styles are active, the control uses the UXTheme API to render the checkbox control, otherwise it uses the bitmap resource (see `PreDrawItemThemed` and `PreDrawItemNonThemed` in *winctrl3.cpp*). If you requested Visual Styles and run on a supported Windows OS (Windows 8 or later), the `CCheckListBox` control won't need the bitmap resource.

Comment: This is not to say that you can just ignore the failed debug assertion. This could well be the result of module state management gone wrong. [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn058-mfc-module-state-implementation) explains why state management is important and how it needs to be implemented.

Comment: @IInspectable Now that is interesting. `IsAppThemed` returns TRUE for both debug and release builds. I confirmed this with a message box. So maybe they got a bug then and shoudl not be trying to load the bitmap when the app is using a theme! Either way, I know I can now hit Ignore. So thank you.

Comment: The bitmap resource needs to be loaded *before* it is possible to determine whether Visual Styles are active. That's what the comment in `_AFX_CHECKLIST_STATE`'s constructor notes. An architectural constraint, not a bug. Though, more importantly, I was expressly trying to convince you, that ignoring the failure isn't safe. If code cannot find a resource that's compiled into a module, you are probably dealing with module state management that's wayward. Ignoring this now will have you spend hours, days, weeks on debugging hard to diagnose failures.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I just tried to read the module state article and need to digest it. I don't have any "code" for the language DLL files. Side note though, and kinda weird. if you create a raw MFC dialog app and add the check list box and build however you like (english) and use a thirdparty resource viewer it doesn't have bitmaps anyway. Thanks for all your help though.